# NextJS - SSR Getting _next/data.json requst

Tags: next.js

I have a page uses `getServerSideProps` and when I request this page directly everything works as expected but when I request this page on the client through next router I see request which has this JSON path like `https://****/_next/data/uU96tn57Tno0N1e5kERHx/data.json`

How can I prevent this request when accessing the page on the client side through next router?

Should I use shallow routeing? And handle the request on useEffects method?

My page looks like

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
    return resp.data.message;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

function Paged(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.dogstring}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const dogstring = await sendGetRequest();
  return {
    props: {
      dogstring: dogstring,
    },
  };
}

export default Paged;
```

**Accessing the page**

```
<Link href={'/paged'}><a>ssr page</a></Link>
```

I want to prevent the JSON path request because I don't want to be 2 latency to the SSR page when accessing it through next router on the client side

Comment: That's how `getServerSideProps` works, see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#technical-details-2. _"I don't want to be 2 latency to the SSR page when accessing it through next router on the client side"_ I don't understand what you mean in that line - why would you want to prevent this request?

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks a lot for replaying! I mean, whenever I access the page using `push` method you would see a request goes to `https://****/_next/data/uU96tn57Tno0N1e5kERHx/data.json`and this is the first latency and in the background `NextJS` send a request to the real server here is the second latency

Comment: I see, are you noticing a significant delay because of it? Using [SSR Caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching) strategies could help with that.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, exactly! Because I uploaded the NextJS project to a really far server.
What do you think of my solution for this.
As I read in the NextJS document that when using `shallow` routing it won't run `getServerSideProps` then I handle the fetch request in `useEffect` and run it only if it came from push routering

Comment: Is it a good solution or should I go with SSR Caching?

Comment: Do you think the SSR Caching would cause a stale data?

Comment: It could depend on your requirements, I would personally go with SSR caching most of the time.

Comment: I will go with SSR caching so! I really appreciate your help answering my questions. Thanks a lot!